# Php code igniter does not return error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have downloaded an example of SSI implementation to use it in *codeigniter* and I read the documentation as well as the code and now I am modifying it. I had only changed the database name, tables and its fields in it. And now the system does not show errors for database not found or table does not exist and undefined field name, while I was expecting errors. I know there is error of database name, table name and also in table fields but my problem is, that the system does not throw any errors regarding to the database. I did use `try ... catch` construct, but instead of throwing errors it simply executes..

Am i missing some thing in library to be corrected or to be written?

I am using code *igniter*.

Comment: have you autoloaded database library?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked loading of model ?
Example

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

Error does not show when model in CodeIgniter is not loaded.

-Thanks  ( =

Answer (score 0):

open the index.php file and make sure that line that defines the ENVIRONMENT is 
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); and not testing or production

try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

to the top of the file where you want to show errors or before the connection string (database.php)

Comment: I have checked that it is same as you have said like define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');It still is not working

Comment: I tested by replacing with null in database.php $db['default']['database'] = ''; It still does not throw any error.Oh my